# SQL Adding the number of occurrences from different tables

Tags: mysql, sql, addition

I have written a query:

```
SELECT  `name` , COUNT( * ) FROM  `daily` GROUP BY  `Name` 
UNION 
SELECT  `name` , COUNT( * ) FROM  `monday` GROUP BY  `Name`
```

I am getting this result

```
Name  |  Count(*)
-------------------

Person 1 | 10 |

Person 2 | 05 |

Person 3 | 00 |

Person 1 | 08 |

Person 2 | 10 |
```

I simply want to get this result:

```
Name  |  Count(*)
-------------------
Person 1 | 18 |

Person 2 | 15 |

Person 3 | 00 |
```

I want to add the two values from the two tables against the same 'name'. What join command do I use here ?

Comment: I am using MySQL. Sorry for the wrong tag :-(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to do the `union` *before* the aggregation:

```
select name, count(*)
from (select name from daily union all select name from monday) t
group by name;
```

You can also pre-aggregate the values, although I'm not sure if there is a performance gain in MySQL to do this:

```
select name, sum(cnt)
from ((select name, count(*) as cnt from daily group by name)
      union all
      (select name, count(*) as cnt from monday group by name)
     ) t
group by name;
```

Answer (score 1):

This is not tested

```
select name, SUM(total)
from ( 
  SELECT name , COUNT( * ) as total
  FROM daily 
  GROUP BY Name 

  UNION 

  SELECT name ,COUNT( * ) as total
  FROM monday 
  GROUP BY Name 
) 
GROUP BY name;
```

Hope this works :)

Comment: This Returns an Error: #1248 - Every derived table must have its own alias

Comment: You should use `union all` in this case. Otherwise, if one name has the same count in both tables you'll only get that value (when it should be twice that).

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT [name], Sum(NameCount) as [Count] 
FROM (SELECT [name] , COUNT(*) AS NameCount
    FROM daily GROUP BY [name] 
  UNION ALL SELECT [name] , COUNT(*) AS NameCount 
    FROM monday GROUP BY [name] ) AS Counts
GROUP BY [name]
```

Comment: I wrote this for SQL Server but the concept should be the same.

Comment: This returns syntax error, I tried it in some other ways as well but still it gives  #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax at Line 1

Comment: I am assuming that you can't use the [] in MySQL.